# How can I prevent icons from moving on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I just upgraded to Windows 10.   All in all it seems ok, but occasionally the icons all rearrange back to the left (not sure exactly what causes it.  Occasionally switching to another user and back, rebooting?).   I definitely have the "auto-arrange" option disabled.

Anyway to prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance
Ben

Comment: This can happen if you change screen resolution. Have you been into safe mode, or used remote access?

Comment: I've never changed screen resolution, or used safe mode, or remote access.   But it still happens regularly (but not 100% of the time).

I read somewhere that updating the display drivers might help.  Tried it, but it didn't help this problem.

I ended up using the DesktopOK 3rd party utility that saves icon locations.  That seems to work fine (had to change the default language from German.  Sort of weird)

Comment: One more thought, my kids have their own separate logins on this box and they *do* use a different screen resolutions.    Maybe a bug related to that?  I will try some experiements.

Comment: I don't know that it's a bug: if you reduce the resolution, some of the icons will be off-screen, so Windows moves them so that they remain visible. If other users have different accounts, they will have their own desktop icon set, but icons in the public desktop will be common to all and will be moved if affected by resolution changes or if someone logs in with auto-arrange enabled. As a work-round, you could move all the public desktop icons to a back-up location, then copy into each user desktop, but you will have extra work to do whenever you install or remove software, or add users.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the problem/bug was related to different logins on the computer having different resolutions set.  I've set all logins to the same resolution, and my problem seems to have gone away.

There's a slight chance something else changed at the same time (that happened to fix the problem), but I don't think so.

Ben

Comment: Good to hear that the problem was resolved, one way or another!  Please remember to return back here after the two-day moratorium to officially select your own answer as the accepted solution.